# Combine multiple revisions of word files into one file - thesis revision

Tags: microsoft-word, comparison, file-compare

I wish you could help me in this !

I sent my Thesis to my supervisor. she sent a revision of the first 4 chapters, and she is currently working on the remaining chapters.

I wanted to save time by working on the comments and revisions she had for the first 4 chapters. She will send me another file with the remaining revisions, and I assume she continued working on the same file for revisions/comments.  I am not sure how can I combine her new revisions for the remaining chapters to the file I started to work on.

Any suggestions are valuable !

Thanks

Comment: any ideas to solve?

Comment: Just work with 4 chapters and when she send the remaining copy the after 4 chapters in her file and paste after the 4th on the one you are working with